# need optimize mysql query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I want to do optimize this query. I have give statistics for using tables.

`products` and `products_categories` table have around 500000 record. But for below mentioned `category` it has 1600 record. I have create slots for this 1600 records. Every `product` can have minimum 1 slot and maximum 10 slots. But slot table have around 300000 record. `slot table` can have already expire slots also. I want to get products, which are going to expire soon come first and rest of the products come behind of this products.

I have created index for `end_time` column. But I used conditional operator, so index not using in this query. I want to optimize this query. kindly tell me the best way.

```sql
EXPLAIN
SELECT
  xcart_products.*
FROM xcart_products
  INNER JOIN xcart_products_categories
    ON xcart_products_categories.productid = xcart_products.productid
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
           t1.*
         FROM bvira_megahour_time_slot t1
           LEFT OUTER JOIN bvira_megahour_time_slot t2
         ON (t1.product_id = t2.product_id
             AND t1.end_time > t2.end_time
             AND t1.end_time > NOW())
         WHERE t2.product_id IS NULL) as bvira_megahour_time_slot
    ON bvira_megahour_time_slot.product_id = xcart_products.productid
WHERE xcart_products_categories.categoryid = '4410'
    AND xcart_products.saleid = 2
GROUP BY xcart_products.productid
```

Below is the result of explain query.

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY    xcart_products_categories    ref     PRIMARY,cpm,productid,orderby,pm    cpm     4   const   1523    Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY     xcart_products  eq_ref  PRIMARY,saleid  PRIMARY     4   wwwbvira_xcart.xcart_products_categories.productid  1   Using where
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    77215   
2   DERIVED     t1  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    398907  
2   DERIVED     t2  ref     i_product_id,i_end_time     i_product_id    4   wwwbvira_xcart.t1.product_id    4   Using where; Not exists
```

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten your query as follows:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT p.*
FROM xcart_products p
INNER JOIN xcart_products_categories c
    ON c.productid = p.productid
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM bvira_megahour_time_slot t1
    LEFT JOIN bvira_megahour_time_slot t2
      ON (   t1.product_id = t2.product_id
         AND t1.end_time   > t2.end_time
         AND t1.end_time   > NOW()
      )
    WHERE t2.product_id IS NULL
) AS bvira_megahour_time_slot
  ON bvira_megahour_time_slot.product_id = p.productid
WHERE c.categoryid = '4410'
  AND p.saleid = 2
GROUP BY p.productid
```

Please make sure that you have following compound (multi-column) indexes:

```
bvira_megahour_time_slot:  (product_id, end_time)
xcart_products:            (productid, sale_id)
xcart_products_categories: (productid, category_id)
                        or (category_id, productid)
```

With these indexes, it should work much better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it was not working better. I have created composite index mentioned table. Before creating index query execution took 10.3731 sec. After create index it took 10.2148 sec. It is not optimized well.
CREATE INDEX i_product_id_end_time ON bvira_megahour_time_slot(product_id, end_time);
CREATE INDEX i_productid_saleid ON xcart_products(productid, saleid);
CREATE INDEX i_productid_categoryid ON xcart_products_categories(productid, categoryid);